# Unable to update firebase function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions, npm-install

I am unable to update my firebase functions. It is showing error-

```
C:\Users\MYName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\index.js:47
        throw new Error(`@grpc/grpc-js only works on Node ${supportedNodeVersions}`);
        ^

    Error: @grpc/grpc-js only works on Node ^8.13.0 || >=10.10.0
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Bhaskar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\index.js:47:11)
        at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
        at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Bhaskar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\google-gax\build\src\grpc.js:37:14)
        at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
        at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

How to solve this issue?Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The error message:

> Error: @grpc/grpc-js only works on Node ^8.13.0 || >=10.10.0

is suggesting that you should be using one of the recommended node versions on your local machine.  Try installing node 10 instead of whatever you're using now.  Check it with `node --version`.

Answer (score 0):

I was having an issue in which firebase would attempt to update all of my functions, then I would get an error, for every cloud function, of: "Error Failed to update function"

Reverting to a previous version of my `package.json` folder fixed the problem. Specifically, I had installed `@firebase/app`, which I did not need, and had changed versions of `firebase`, `firebase-admin`, and `firebase-functions`.

Here is the package.json version that actually worked:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/msal-node": "^1.3.0",
    "@firebase/firestore": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/bn.js": "^5.1.0",
    "@types/json-bigint": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "firebase": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.15.7",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "web3-utils": "^1.5.2"
  },
```

Here is the version that did not work:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/msal-node": "^1.3.0",
    "@firebase/app": "^0.7.5",
    "@firebase/firestore": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/bn.js": "^5.1.0",
    "@types/json-bigint": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "firebase": "^9.2.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.15.4",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "web3-utils": "^1.5.2"
  },
```

[Here is a screenshot of the two commits. The previous (red) version is what I had to revert to, to get my functions to update.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r11M8.jpg)